# Java classloader and memory management

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

When the classloader loads class `A`, which classes will be loaded by the classloader and in which memory location in the JVM would these objects be put? If `flag` is `false` will class `D` be loaded?

```
public class A {
  B b = new B();
  C c = null;
  static int i;
  int j;

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    boolean flag = true;
    if (flag) {
        m1();
    }
    A a = new A();
    a.m2();
  }

  private static void m1() {
    D d = new D();
    d.print();
  }

  private void m2() {
    c = new C();
    System.out.println("inside m2");
  }

  private static void m3() {
    System.out.println("inside m3");
  }
}
```

Comment: declaration of B is 
static B b = new B();

Comment: Just run with `-verbose:class` and see. Besides that, it’s a good habit to post *complete* code in questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which all classes will be loaded by classloader

`A` and `Object` as a minimum. Depending on the implementation, the JVM might load `B` and `C` on class initialisation or when you create your first instance. `C` might not be initialised until `m2()` is called.

> in which memory location in JVM these objects would be put

Small objects are placed in the Eden space regardless of which ClassLoader you use.

> If flag is false will class D be loaded

Probably not but it depends on the JVM.